# llvm JIT add library to module

Tags: c++, llvm, jit

I am working on a JIT that uses LLVM. The language has a small run-time written in C++ which I compile down to LLVM IR using clang

```
clang++ runtime.cu --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_50 -c -emit-llvm
```

and then load the *.bc files, generate additional IR, and execute on the fly. The reason for the CUDA stuff is that I want to add some GPU acceleration to the runtime. However, this introduces CUDA specific external functions which gives errors such as:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'cudaSetupArgument' which could not be resolved!
```

As discussed [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/514679/compiling-error-undefined-reference-to-cudamalloc-39-/), this is usually solved by including the appropriate libraries when compiling the program:

```
g++ main.c cmal.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
```

However, I am not sure how to include libraries in JITed modules using LLVM. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425797/linking-llvm-jit-code-to-external-c-functions) question which suggested that is used to be possible to add libraries to modules in the JIT like this:

```
[your module]->addLibrary("m");
```

Unfortunately, this has been deprecated. Can anyone tell me the best way to do this now? Let me know if I need to provide more information!

Furthermore, I am not really sure if this is the best way to be incorporating GPU offloading into my JIT, so if anyone can point me to a better method then please do :)

Thanks!

EDIT: I am using LLVM 5.0 and the JIT engine I am using is from `llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h`, more specifically I create it like this:

```
EngineBuilder EB(std::move(module));
ExecutionEngine *EE = EB.create(targetMachine);
```

Comment: Which version of LLVM and which JIT engine do you use?

Comment: @AlexDenisov I have answered your question in an edit :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to teach your JIT engine about other symbols explicitly.

If they are in a dynamic library (`dylib`, `so`, `dll`) then you can just call

```
sys::DynamicLibrary::LoadLibraryPermanently("path_to_some.dylib")
```

with a path to the dynamic library.

If the symbols are in an object file or an archive, then it requires a bit more work: you would need to load them into memory and add to the `ExecutionEngine` using its APIs.

Here is an example for an object file:

```
std::string objectFileName("some_object_file.o");

ErrorOr<std::unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer>> buffer =
  MemoryBuffer::getFile(objectFileName.c_str());

if (!buffer) {
  // handle error
}

Expected<std::unique_ptr<ObjectFile>> objectOrError =
  ObjectFile::createObjectFile(buffer.get()->getMemBufferRef());

if (!objectOrError) {
  // handle error
}

std::unique_ptr<ObjectFile> objectFile(std::move(objectOrError.get()));

auto owningObject = OwningBinary<ObjectFile>(std::move(objectFile),
                                             std::move(buffer.get()));

executionEngine.addObjectFile(std::move(owningObject));
```

For archives replace template types `ObjectFile` with `Archive`, and call

```
executionEngine.addArchive(std::move(owningArchive));
```

at the end.