# How to link c++ standard library in LLVM's JIT?

Tags: llvm, jit, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have custom functions written by c++, and they are using lots of c++ standard libraries, such as `iostream`, `map`, `vector`, i can add my functions to JIT using `addObjectFile`, but the `standard libraries' functions` cannot be found, how cound i link them with my JIT?

My case:
**ffi.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int add(int a, int b) {
  std::cout << ">>add function run" << std::endl;
  return a + b;
}
```

**main.cpp**, the `built/ffi` is created by `clang++ ffi.cpp -c -o build/ffi`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  InitLLVM X(argc, argv);
  InitializeNativeTarget();
  InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();
  ThreadSafeContext context(std::make_unique<LLVMContext>());

  ExitOnError ExitOnErr;

  auto JTMB = ExitOnErr(JITTargetMachineBuilder::detectHost());
  JTMB.setCodeModel(CodeModel::Small);

  auto jit =
      ExitOnErr(LLJITBuilder()
                    .setJITTargetMachineBuilder(std::move(JTMB))
                    .create());

  char ffi_file[] = "build/ffi";
  jit->addObjectFile(ExitOnErr(errorOrToExpected(MemoryBuffer::getFileAsStream(ffi_file))));
```

The `add` function can be found, but the functions of iostream cannot be found, and run with error:

```
JIT session error: Symbols not found: [ __Unwind_Resume, __ZNKSt3__16locale9use_facetERNS0_2idE, __ZNKSt3__18ios_base6getlocEv, __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEmc, __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED1Ev, __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE3putEc, __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE5flushEv, __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryC1ERS3_, __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryD1Ev, __ZNSt3__14coutE, __ZNSt3__15ctypeIcE2idE, __ZNSt3__16localeD1Ev, __ZNSt3__18ios_base33__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrowEv, __ZNSt3__18ios_base5clearEj, __ZSt9terminatev, ___cxa_begin_catch, ___cxa_end_catch, ___gxx_personality_v0, _memset, _strlen ]
Failed to materialize symbols: { (0x7fd514708170, { __ZNSt3__124__put_character_sequenceIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_PKS4_m, __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc, __ZNSt3__111char_traitsIcE11eq_int_typeEii, __ZNSt3__111char_traitsIcE3eofEv, __ZNSt3__111char_traitsIcE6lengthEPKc, _main, _link, _add, ___clang_call_terminate, __ZNSt3__116__pad_and_outputIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEENS_19ostreambuf_iteratorIT_T0_EES6_PKS4_S8_S8_RNS_8ios_baseES4_ }) }
```

Comment: Could you post the command you used used to build (compile, link) main.cpp?

Comment: Found this that might be related/helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105342/llvm-jit-add-library-to-module